# 1305. FUNCTION retail_events_db.quantity_sold does not exist

Tags: sql, mysql

i executed the following command it works as shown
**SELECT *
FROM fact_events;***

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXzKI.png)
above query shows all data including column= quantity_sold(before_promo)
but when i runt the following command to see the result of the column *quantity_sold(before_promo)*

**SELECT quantity_sold(before_promo)
FROM fact_events;**

the following error is showing even though quantity_sold(before_promo) is showing when executed all data in the table
**Error Code: 1305. FUNCTION retail_events_db.quantity_sold does not exist**
please help me

i tried and to explore in the internet and even #youtube videos but unable to get answer

Comment: mysql thinks quantity_sold is a function - no surprise given this is how a function is invoked. - quantity_sold(before_promo)  is a poor choice for a column name but if you are stuck with it enclose in backticks when querying.

Comment: I've never used a column name that way, but try adding back-ticks to the column to see if it helps avoid the error?

Comment: Related [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)